# Why is every point in an open interval $(a,b)$ not a limit point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If I have an open interval $\Bbb R\supset A=(a,b)$ then I can pick any $x:a<x<b$ and make a ball with center $x$ which contains a point inside the interval.

However, [this article from proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_Points_of_Open_Real_Interval) says otherwise. Why is that?

Edit: The article did not say otherwise, the way of writing just confused me, sorry.

Comment: Indeed they are all limit points of $A$. So are $a$ and $b$. The article does not say they are not limit points.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP retracted question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article says:

> Then the limit points of $(a\,. \, . \, b)$ are:
>
> the points $(a\,. \, . \, b)$ itself
>
> and
>
> the points $a$ and $b$.

Thus, it does in fact say that every $x$ with $a < x < b$ is a limit point as this is a point in $(a\,. \, . \, b)$ and covered by the first part.

Possibly the formulation "the points $(a\,. \, . \, b)$ itself" confused you, and I have to agree it seems not optimal.

Answer (score 3):

That article doesn't say anything of the sort. It says that every point in $(a,b)$ is a limit point, which is true and consistent with what you said.